# Issues when installing Android Studio on Mac

Tags: javascript, android, xcode, android-studio, installation

I am a mac user every time i install android studio it starts downloading some components and ends up showing this message can any one please help to install this software please check the below image which shows the message I get when i started installing android studio

[image]

Comment: Refer to this link for instructions.
https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Answer (score 0):

The AndroidStudio requires to download Android APIs and some support tools and libraries that your system is failing to install. It may be cause of poor internet connection or low disk space.